# When and How to use *We are to* and *We have to* in Sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Please explain how to use *We are to* and *We have to* in Sentence.

e.g.

a) We are to pay him amount.

And

b) We have to pay him amount.

a) If we are to teach real peace in this world then....

And

b) If we have to teach real peace in this world then....

Answer (score 4):

"We are to" means we are supposed to, "we have to" means we must.

> a) We are to pay him the amount.

Means we are supposed to pay him the amount.

> b) We have to pay him the amount.

Means we must pay him the amount.

Comment: *an/the* amount...

Comment: @user3169 The question didn't say that.

Comment: @user3169 I changed it anyways.

Comment: It's good that you changed it.  Answers should contain grammatical English in their examples.  I wonder, though, if the OP didn't mean to use *amount* as a placeholder, standing in for something like "We have to pay him **five dollars**".  In that case, the article would be unnecessary.